# Setting up an NGRX8 store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am attempting to set up a NGRX store for this object

```
export interface ListItem {
   id?: string;
   name: string;
}
```

to be shown in the list component

```
<li *ngFor="let shopping of listItems | async">
          {{ shopping.name }}
        </li>
```

However the initial state does not appear to be showing up.
Here are the associated actions and reducer files

reducer

```
const initialState: Array<ListItem> = [
  {
    id: '1775935f-36fd-467e-a667-09f95b917f6d',
    name: 'Diet Coke',
  }
];

// tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name
const _listReducer = createReducer(initialState,
  on(add, (state, {payload}) => ({
    ...state,
    payload
  }))
)

export function listReducer(state, action) {
  return _listReducer(state, action.payload);
}
```

actions

```
export const add = createAction(
  '[List Component] Add',
  props<{payload: {item: ListItem}}>());
```

the entry in my app.module

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      count: counterReducer,
      list: listReducer
    }),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: environment.production })
  ]
```

and here is where I am attempting to access the store

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  listItems$: Observable<Array<ListItem>>;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.listItems$ = store.pipe(select('list'));
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

I am very new to the NGRX world so I am likely missing something simple.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is something not working? Or, are you just asking us to check your work?

Comment: The store does not appear to be populating the component mentioned. I updated the question.

Comment: Just to be sure, the `add` action is not being dispatched yet, right?

Comment: it is not, currently I am just trying to initialize the store and display the initial state

Comment: i think you are destructuring the payload in the action.payload, try changing this part: _listReducer(state, action.payload) to _listReducer(state, action)

Comment: Try doing `return _listReducer(state, action);` - if that doesn't change anything a reproduction will help because I'm not seeing anything wrong.

Comment: Your VM has a field `listItems$` but in your view, you use `listItems`. Is this just a typo in here?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen state pulled from the store like this:

```
store.pipe(select('list'))
```

Normally it would look something like this:

```
this.store.select(fromFeature.getData1);
```

And that would be defined somewhere (I have it in my index.ts file in my state folder) as:

```
export const getData1 = createSelector(
    getFeatureState,
    state => state.feature.Data1
);
```

This github project is a good reference for setting up ngrx: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-NgRx-GettingStarted/tree/master/APM-Demo5/src/app/products/state